# Custom arrayadapter combines lists used in different fragments of same activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I have MainActivity activity which has 3 fragments. Those 3 fragments use same arrayadapter class MessageListAdapter. When i populate listView in my fragments using different ArrayLists using MessageListAdapter it combines all those ArrayLists and displays in each fragment. I want each fragment to display its own list.

MessageListAdapter:

```
public class MessageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message>{

Context context;

public MessageListAdapter(Context c, int resourceId, ArrayList<Message> list) {
    super(c, resourceId, list);
    this.context = c;
}

//...
}
```

HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
View view;
ListView listView1;
ArrayList<Message> contactMessages;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_layout, container, false);
    TextView welcomeMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.welcomeMessage);
    Account acc = new Account();
    welcomeMessage.setText("Welcome " + acc.getName() + "!");
    contactMessages = new Message().getContactMessages();
    listView1 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.homeList);
    MessageListAdapter adapter = new MessageListAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.activity_message, contactMessages);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
        
    });
    return view;
}

}
```

ProfileFragment:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {
View view;
Intent intent;
ListView listView2;
ArrayList<Message> personalMessages;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_layout, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addMessage);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button addFriendButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addFriend);
    addFriendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddFriendActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        
    });
    personalMessages = new Message().getPersonalMessages();
//  Log.i("Personal messages ArrayList: ", personalMessages.toString());
    listView2 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileList);
    MessageListAdapter adapter = new MessageListAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.activity_message, personalMessages);
    listView2.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView2.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    return view;
}
}
```

Also have 3rd fragment which will use this same MessageListAdapter, but i have not implemented it yet due to running into this problem.

I made screenshots to make it easier to understand:
Items with orange pictures are supposed to be shown only in ProfileFragment and item with blue picture is supposed to be shown only in HomeFragment

[image: Fragments]

Comment: Are you saying that all listviews contains the same set of values ??

Comment: Yes, both lists contain same objects in ProfileFragment and HomeFragment

Comment: have you verified that "ArrayList" loads the different values ??

Comment: Sorry for bothering with question. Figures that if you use regular static arraylist inside an object class it somehow combines them all together. I fixed this issue by using SQLite database instead of holding data inside static arraylist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies in using static ArrayList inside Message class. addPersonalMessage adds Message object into personalMessages list and addContactMessage adds Message object into contactMessages list. After i built all the messages according to their type and put them inside lists separately, for some reason application combines those 2 lists. This is why i end up with similar content in both listviews in fragments. Solved problem by using SQLite database instead of using static variables.
Message:

```
public class Message {

private String author;
private String messageTitle;
private Bitmap messageImage;

private static ArrayList<Message> personalMessages = new ArrayList<Message>();
private static ArrayList<Message> contactMessages = new ArrayList<Message>();

public Message() {

}
public Message(String a, String t, Bitmap b) {
    this.author = a;
    this.messageTitle = t;
    this.messageImage = b;
}

public void addPersonalMessage() {
    personalMessages.add(this);
}
public void addContactMessage() {
    contactMessages.add(this);
}

}
```